# Can i use html tags in struts2 form?

Tags: struts2

Can i use html form tags in struts 2 form? 
Like 
`<input type='text' value='' />
<input type='submit' />`
Will the values be posted through struts2?

Comment: The logic must tell you the answer, since `<s:textfield>` and `<s:submit>` will be rendered in the jsp as `<input type='text' ...` and `<input type='submit'...`

Answer (score 3):

It's not at all mandatory to use struts2 tags. You could go with regular HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Of course.

This is one of those questions you can just *try*.

All the S2 form tags *do* is emit HTML, filling in various attributes as required. (It's slightly more complicated than that, but ultimately, they spit out an HTML form field.)

Flip your question on its head: why *wouldn't* a hand-crafted input tag be sent via the normal browser HTTP submission process? What mechanism could *prevent* it from working? How is the request body of from such a form submission *different* from one where the input tags are S2 custom tags?

These questions are all trivial to explore.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
You must give them a `name`; the name will be used to set properties (with correct type conversion) in the struts action.
If you call an input `somename` the `setSomename()` will be called on post.

Answer (score 0):

**If simple HTML used you wont be able to call struts tags inside it eg:**

```
<s:submit cssStyle="submit_button" id='newrc%{#stat.index}.%{#questionIndex.index}' name="newrc%{#stat.index}.%{#questionIndex.index}" onclick="return newrcClick(this)" value="+" />
```

This works but below code does not provide values for id and name from values stack thus :name="newrc%{#stat.index}.%{#questionIndex.index}"

```
<input type="button" cssStyle="submit_button" id='newrc%{#stat.index}.%{#questionIndex.index}' name="newrc%{#stat.index}.%{#questionIndex.index}" onclick="return newrcClick(this)" value="+" />
```